# How to change column width in baposter?

Tags: baposter

Is it possible to change the width of individual columns in `baposter`?  By default, all columns are of the same width, and I can't seem to find how to change that.  Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: After doing more reading, I think the only option is to increase the total number of columns, and let the column I want to be wider than others span multiple columns.  This can be done using the posterbox span option.

Comment: The fact that the columns are of equal width is commonly the case when dealing with TeX's paragraph setting over page (or column) breaks. The entire paragraph is set to a specific width, and it's just easier if everything is the same width. Otherwise you'll have to fiddle around with `\parshape`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change that using the argument `span`: `span=2` for example means that your box will have twice the width of an elementary column :

```
\headerbox{Name of my box}{name=nickname,span=2,column=1,row=0}{
content of my box
}
```

or

```
\headerbox{Name of my box}{name=nickname,span=3,column=1,below=nickname_box_just_above}{
content
}
```

Comment: Quick question: is it possible to make a poster column occupy column halves? I tried to use `span=1.5`, but it doesn't compile...

Comment: Ever found a work around fractional span? e.g. ```span = 1.5```

Comment: @FrancescaBasini You can add `columns=4` in the `\begin{poster}` environment. Then you can set the `span` to be 2 to have equal width boxes.

Comment: @RobertP. @FrancescaBasini Why not double the total number of columns, so you have to double all the spans as well? E.g. `span=1.5` with `columns=2` becomes `span=3` with `columns=4`.